# @AspectJ pointcut for subclasses of a class with an annotation

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm looking for a pointcut that matches method executions in classes that subclass a class with a specific annotation. The excellent [AspectJ cheat sheet](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/) helped me to create the following pointcut:

```
within(@my.own.annotations.AnnotationToMatch *) && execution(* *(..))
```

This matches all method calls of a class A that carries the @AnnotationToMatch, but not method of a class B that extends A. How can I match both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public aspect AnnotatedParentPointcutAspect {   

//introducing empty marker interface
declare parents : (@MyAnnotation *) implements TrackedParentMarker;

public pointcut p1() : execution(* TrackedParentMarker+.*(..));

before(): p1(){
    System.out.println("Crosscutted method: "
            +thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()
            +"." 
            +thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName());
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For the benefit of others: if you use the annotation style, the declare parents translates to @DeclareParents("(@MyAnnotation *)")
    private TrackedParentMarker emptyMixinForClassesWithMyAnnotation;

Comment: That works well for super-classes, but not so well for interfaces. I.e. in code such as `MyInterface o = new MyClass()` it looks loke `MyClass` gets loaded before the interface and the condition doesn't match. Adding a `println(MyInterface.class)` before the statement fixes the problem, but is not feasible requirement for library aspects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Another and simpler possibility is to declare the annotation as @Inherited - thus it applies to the subclasses as well.

Comment: But it won't work if you cannot declare annotation as @Inherited. E.g. base classes from third party libraries.